# Delete first 4 characters after a comma in r

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a vector with rows such as:

```
/en/house/125,/en/house/145,/en/house/06
/en/house/45,/fr/house/22,/fr/house/34
```

I would like to remove the /en/, /fr/ etc, knowing that there are 24 2-letter possibilities. In other words, I would like to delete the first 4 character of a row, and the first 4 character everytime there is a comma in the row (I keep the comma). 
The first one is easy, i just used:

`apply(vectorA, 2, function(x)gsub('\\s+','',x))`

but for the one behind the comma it seems less obvious. 
Does anyone knows how to easily make that function please?

The expect output should be :

```
house/125,house/145,house/06
house/45,house/22,house/34
```

Comment: If always 4 chr [`(^|,).{4}` and replace with `'\1'`](https://regex101.com/r/VNn0XV/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `stringr::str_replace_all`?

```
"/en/house/125,/en/house/145,/en/house/06" -> string
stringr::str_replace_all(string, "/[a-z]{2}/", "")
```

This produces:

```
[1] "house/125,house/145,house/06"
```

This assumes all tags between the two forward slashes are two characters long and in lower case.

Comment: +1. Same could be done with `gsub("/[a-z]{2}/", "", string)` though, which would make the installation of a package unnecessary.

Comment: This one works perfectly. The tags will always be 2-character long indeed. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you need to only replace `/[a-z]{2}/` at the start of a string or after comma.

You need the following regex:

```
(^|,)/[a-z]{2}/
```

and replace with `\1` backreference that will put back the comma if the capturing group matched it. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sScAb0/1).

**Details**

- `(^|,)` - Group 1 (later referred to with `\1` replacement backreference from the replacement pattern): a start of string (`^`) or (`|`) a comma
- `/` - a slash
- `[a-z]{2}` - two lowercase ASCII letters
- `/` - a slash.

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/qDwjvx):

```
x <- c("/en/house/125,/en/house/145,/en/house/06", "/en/house/45,/fr/house/22,/fr/house/34", "/es/do/45,/ro/nu/22,/ja/hs/34")
gsub("(^|,)/[a-z]{2}/", "\\1", x)
## => [1] "house/125,house/145,house/06" 
##    [2] "house/45,house/22,house/34"  
##    [3] "do/45,nu/22,hs/34"
```

Comment: Perfect, so only one instruction actually. Thanks a lot!